# Trying to check if any unwanted keys adding in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
d = {'name':"nag","rollno":23,"location":"Bangalore"}
if list(d.keys())!=['name','rollno','location']:
    print("unwanted keys are present")
else:
    print("No unwanted keys")
```

Is this code fine or if there is an any better approach than this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you need a data structure with exactly 3 elements of a given name, why not use a class or a `NamedTuple`?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a [set cmparison](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#comparisons):

```
if {'name', 'rollno', 'location'} == d.keys(): # or <= ?
    print("unwanted keys are present")
else:
    print("No unwanted keys")
```

that way there is no need for an additional `list` call and you are flexible if you want to use other comparisons such as `<=` or `<`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want single line if else condition use the following code

```
"Unwanted Keys" if d.keys() not in(['name','rollno','location']) else "Correct Keys"
```

Or

```
"Unwanted Keys" if d.keys() !=(['name','rollno','location']) else "Correct Keys"
```